# Run single java file with standard main(String [] args) method - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

To start with - Yes, I know that this is crazy/strange. But I need it :).

**I want to find simpliest way to run single java file** (and prefer non-terminal answers :) - if they are possible ) in Android Studio. I mean random .java file from my Android project in which I'll write main(..) method. And there's one more thing: **I don't want to create any new modules** (I've already seen answers about adding Java library module). I just want to click something and run my (single) file, the same way as I can do it in Eclipse. Is it possible?

Comment: Just create the class with the main method, right click and "Run 'your class'" i use intellij idea and should be the same in android studio.

Comment: Ok it works - but as I see only when my project is well build - because this method invokes some gradle tasks. (I even tried it earlier - but on project with some errors and then it didn't work). Anyway - do I really need to run gradle to print "Hello world" on terminal :) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If nothing else, you can make a quick JUnit test that calls your class's main method.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I didn't think about that because I just wanted to fast test something small inside my files, but you partially solved my problem the same as luisdurazoa and you get +25.

Answer (score 20):

One thing that might be confusing  you, like it was confusing me:

If there is the standard method to start Java application

```
public static void main (String[] args ) {
// your block here

}
```

Android Studio will automatically give an option "Run YourClass.mainActivity()", when you right-click anywhere in the editor's editing space.

Just right click in the Java file and there will be an option to run that particular Java class.

Comment: This does not work. Gradle tries to build project and fails.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way (for me) is to do a **right click** in your editor and select "**Run ClassName.main()**". See screenshot. Using Android Studio version 1.4.1.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

1. Create the class with `main()` method:

   ```java
   public class Test1 {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("hello1");
     }
   }
   ```
2. Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> for Mac)

It will compile, assemble and print `hello1`

Answer (score 5):

## Solution：

- 1.Create a java class in any package of your project with Android Studio.
- 2.Provide a main() method：

```java
    package com.example.demo;

    public class test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("hello,java");
        }
    }
```

- 3.Avoid use targetSdk 31 in build.gradle:

```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.demo"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

- 4.Configure /${yourproject}/.idea/gradle.xml:

```xml
<GradleProjectSettings>
        <option name="delegatedBuild" value="false" />
        ....
</GradleProjectSettings>
```

- 5.Sync your project with Gradle Files;
- 6.Last,you can Run single java.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

1. Execute run * * main() with coverage;
2. Modify gradle.xml under. Idea

< GradleProjectSettings> Add a row under the label node

< option name=”delegatedBuild” value=”false” />

https://programmerah.com/tag/android/page/2/

Comment: It might be better to add the image from that post to help explain your solution.

Answer (score 1):

This may be too late but this might help other developers,

If you're using JAVA, you need to write it as told by @Andrey.

If you're using Kotlin, you can simply write a function without making a Class.

```
fun main(){
     println("you")
}
```

This will work.

But, remember, function name should only be **main** and don't use anything that is part of Android JDK inside this main function.

Ex:- if you write

```
fun main(){
   Log.e("you","you")
}
```

Now as Log is part of Android, you'll get runtime exception saying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
```