# How to invoke main method of a java project in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have a small github project which i opened in Android Studio from below link.

https://github.com/adakoda/android-screen-monitor

It has no compilation errors  , But i see no Run Configuration to run that main method from AndroidScreenMonitor.java. And also i dont find a way to create a jar file from this .java .

I tried to help myself with creating RunConfigurations by following the links below:

[Run single java file with standard main(String [] args) method - Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137479/run-single-java-file-with-standard-mainstring-args-method-android-studio)

[Running Java application in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765834/running-java-application-in-android-studio?rq=1)

In Run -> EditConfigurations -> MainClass drop down -> Click 3 dots -> Choose Main Class window ,it doesnt let me select the AndroidScreenMonitor.java file or any file as the main file which means the OK button is never enabled.

Is there a way to fix this issue. So that i can run this project from Android Studio.

Comment: why to use Android Studio to run a java project with a main?
You could use intelliJ IDEA and not mess with android libraries.
I guess there could be a way somehow but I have never tried what you are trying to do. All java modules I have made in Android Studio did not include a main and were created to be used as libraries in Android Projects

Comment: @KlitosG.I tried IntelliJ IDE but and i had the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is an Eclipse project that uses swing. You should not use Android Studio for this, you should use IntelliJ.

I cloned your repository and I am able to build it in IntelliJ, follow this steps to build your project:

- In the first screen of IntelliJ select Import Project
- In import screen, navigate to your project dir and open it.
- Select Eclipse as the external model
- IntelliJ will convert your project to the gradle build system.
- Now your project should build without problem.
- To run in, go Run->Edit Configuration.
- In the top left corner select the plus (+) icon and select application
- In the main class, select the three dots and select your main class.
- Give the configuration a name, suggestion: App and press OK.
- Now in the top right corner, in the dropdown will have the App and a play button, click in the play and your project will run.

Comment: To add to this answer, it also searches for jdk1.5.
you will have to choose a java sdk that you have installed on your computer eg jdk1.8

Comment: Android Studio runs Java apps just as well as Intellij

Comment: @cricket_007 are you sure? Android Studio doesn't have the import screen to select the dependencies. I know that it can import Eclipse projects that use ADT, pure Eclipse project I never tried.

Comment: Android Studio only builds over IntelliJ with Android specific features. Nothing is removed from IntelliJ base featureset

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for your inputs.Thank you @jonathanrz. It worked now and i am able to run it in IntelliJ.