# Test simple java code in android studio independently even if main project has syntax error

Tags: java, android

I tried creating a new file in my android app project in the android studio named "TestCode.java" with code

```
public class TestCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int myStr = 11;
        System.out.println(String.format("%06d",myStr));
    }
}
```

when I ran this particular static method by right-clicking on this file, it still ran Gradle build and gave me the errors from my main project and didn't print the result of this file.

Is there any way to just test this simple java code independently in the same project and avoid Gradle Build for the whole project.

currently, I have to open another program "IntelliJ" to test these simple java codes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run single java file with standard main(String \[\] args) method - Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137479/run-single-java-file-with-standard-mainstring-args-method-android-studio)

Comment: @RajuKomati I tried running JUnit test but it still gives me the error from my project, so that solution didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

You can run [Unit Test in Android](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests) in a following way:

```
class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    fun format_string() {
        val myStr = 11
        println(String.format("%06d", myStr))
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
000011
```

If you are still facing issues, I would suggest to have a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16784855/1868841)

You need to modify your configuration to use `Make, no error check` option instead of `Make`.

You can also have a look to this [Vic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10858442/1868841)

Comment: hi, sry it doesn't work, still gets interrupted by the error in my main project

Comment: can you error you are getting?

Comment: I simply run above code in my Android project and output is displayed without any error

Comment: you might not have any errors in the main project, try this remove any required semicolon from the main file and then run the unit test

Comment: if you have errors in your main project, test will not run

Comment: yeah, that is what I want i want to run simple java code even if the main project has errors, bc the sample code doesn't depend on the main project so it should work somehow, anyway thanks for your effort

Comment: it looks interesting,  I will test it in my project and update the results here, Thanks